# Finding locations along a path in certain radius

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7, flask, postgis

**Scenario:**

I am developing API for a mobile application. In this app, a trip can be created from location X to Y and once trip is created all shipment located on the path from X to Y in a certain radius chosen by the traveler, will be displayed. Shipment origin and destination should be in the selected distance filter range(including origin and destination).

**Problem:**

I am storing start and end locations for all trips as well as for shipments. But not able to understand as to how can i achieve it. Table structures(only relative columns) are as following:

shipments

> id | name | pickup_lat | pickup_lang | dropoff_lat | dropoff_long
>   | creation_date

trips

> id | name | start_date | start_lat | start_long | dest_lat | dest_long | radius | creation_date

I am using PostgresSQL, PostGIS and Python.

Comment: I don't see columns storing geometries for your trips and shipments (the effective paths - should be linestrings)? Have you calculated them already ?

Comment: So far i could only think of google maps but later i found that my approach was wrong. I started learning postgis after doing a lot of research and as you asked, no i couldn't calculate it because as per my understanding i don't know if postgis can calculate actual path rather than the line path. It will be a help if you can tell if i am doing anything wrong and what should i do to correct it

Comment: What do you mean actual path vs line path?

Comment: Actual path is like Google map path and not a line path

Comment: While I don't understand what the question is asking, I encourage you to see [ST_DWithin](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html). Additionally, if your data is in lat/long (SRID=4326), then you can use a `geography` type to use a distance in metres.